# Read 8n2 serial with 88us break and 2 bit MAB (250000 baud) (DMX512) from ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, dmx512, arduino-esp8266

How do i configure the serial port on a ESP8266 to accept DMX? I have found some arduino libraries that does this, but they require a 16MHz processor (the ESP-8266 will be run at 80 or 160MHz)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about the Arduino but provided you can set the baud rate 44K or greater that should get you adequate resolution to read all the bits(4us), MAB(8us) and BREAK(88us).

However Gooding ESP8266 it looks like a WiFi Module for the Arduino. If this is the case are do you actually want to receive Art-Net or sACN via the TCP/IP stack?

Additionally If you are looking to receive DMX, because it's RS485 (Differential pair) you will either need to configure the Arduino for RS485 or (in a pinch, or short cable run) use the positive and Ground to a 422 Receiver, though it might work it's not the best practice and it likely won't be reliable.